# Invalid Security certificate error message after reissuing the SSL Certificate

Tags: security, browser, ssl

In my server I have one SSL Certificate which is valid from 06/09/2009 through 06/09/2011. the client is getting invalid certificate error. I reissued the certificate and installed in the server machine. But still the client is getting the same error. Is there any problem with the Browser. Can anyone reply for this issue. But If I open the page in different machine I can go to the site without any invalid certificate error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had similar problems self signed certs switching to legit certs. The browser seems to cache the cert (though it shouldn't be browser specific)

I have noticed the problem more in Chrome than other browsers. You can try dumping the cache in the browser. You can also run

> certmgr.msc

and see if the expired cert shows up, if it does you should be able to delete it and hit the site again to get the new cert.

*My related question on serverfault:* https://serverfault.com/questions/279984/clearning-chrome-ssl-cache